# How to create two way persistence for a game server using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, event-driven, game-loop

Lets say we are building a spaceship game.  A few object types would be spaceships, and solar systems.  I would like to use Node as the backend.

The issue I am having is how to have both these objects existing and interacting with each other in real time using a callback/event driven system.  For example, how would a ship continually tell the system its location within that system without constantly updating a "location" attribute every few seconds that would be initialized upon the creation of the ship.

Or how would two ships interact with each other?  Things like location, types, etc would all have to be considered.  Would insanely complicated event listeners have to implemented?

Maybe I am making this more difficult than is needed.

Comment: Of course you would need to constantly update your state, how else would you call it "real-time"?

Comment: You don't say it specifically, but its implied I think - this is a multiplayer game?

Comment: Yeah it would be a multiplayer game.  And yes I know you would have to update states constantly.  I guess I was hoping for a simple example of what I am talking about designed for node.

Comment: For a multi player game like this, you would have to update the server and the client like crazy. You can solve this though, by using websockets. By definition, web sockets provide a persistent connection between client and server. You can use socketio, a nodejs module.

Answer (score 0):

For realtime apps you should try meteor.js

http://www.meteor.com